How to export curve vertex animation to gltf/glb file?
I have animated a curve with 2 vertex in python by changing the position of the two vertex coordinates, and when exporting to glb the curve does not move.
I am using blender 4.1.
I animated the curve like this:
def create_straight_curve(point1, point2, curve_name="StraightCurve"):
    # Create a new curve object
    curve_data = bpy.data.curves.new(name=curve_name, type='CURVE')
    curve_data.dimensions = '3D'

    # Create a new spline and add it to the curve
    spline = curve_data.splines.new(type='POLY')
    spline.points.add(count=1)

    # Set the points of the spline
    spline.points[0].co = (*point1, 1)
    spline.points[1].co = (*point2, 1)

    # Create a new object with the curve data
    curve_object = bpy.data.objects.new(curve_name, curve_data)
    bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(curve_object)

    return curve_object


curve = create_straight_curve((x_a, y_a, 0), (x_b, y_b, 0), "StraightCurve")
for frame in range(n):
    curve_data = curve.data
    spline = curve_data.splines[0]
    points = spline.points
    points[0].co = (x_a_v[frame], y_a_v[frame], 0, 1)
    points[1].co = (x_b_v[frame], y_b_v[frame], 0, 1)

    points[0].keyframe_insert(data_path="co", frame=frame+1)
    points[1].keyframe_insert(data_path="co", frame=frame+1)

and it is working fine in blender. I can see the curve moving and changing it size. Basically I am changing the location of the vertex (this is important, I don't want to do object translations, I want to change the position of the vertex).
However when I export this as a gltf/glb file the curve is always static.
I tried adding a mesh (a cube) to the file and animating it, and the cube is moving fine but the curve is still static, so I guess it is something related to the curve type (splines?).
I would like to keep using curves because my end goal is to create an animation with 1000s of curves with bevel and animate them. If I convert each of them to a mesh and animate them it is going to be really big the file.
gltf supports curve objects with bevel, they are displayed as they should, but not the animation.
Thanks!

Exporting is infamous for losing data, since the formats are not as versatile as a Blend file. glTF likely does not support curve animations, but I’d have to look at the official spec to be sure.

I was suspecting that, but I wasn't able to confirm it yet .
